# jQuery Bootstrap Dialog 2 Form Validation

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, dialog, modal-dialog

I'm trying to create a wizard using Nikku's plugin for bootstrap but cannot work out how to integrate jQuery validation.

https://github.com/Nikku/jquery-bootstrap-scripting

I thought that I may be able to use `beforeSend` as a trigger to set off the validation but even though I can prevent the ajax call, the dialog has already started updating.

```
$(document).delegate(".modal", "dialog2.before-send", function(e, xhr, settings) {
    if(settings.type == "POST"){
        // trigger validation abort if fail
        xhr.abort();
    }
});
```

Wizard html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQuery dialog2 plugin</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form class="ajax" method="post" action="nextpage.htm">
            <fieldset>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-actions">
                <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary" />
                <a class="btn close-dialog" href="#">Cancel</a>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any pointers?